# how to add php echo in between do_shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, shortcode

I'm using redux frmaework for my theme option panel. & I'm using meta slider for my homepage. I used this shortcode in my frontpage template to show the slider:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id=21]'); ?>
```

but I want to change the id from my option panel, so I don't have to edit my template each time I replaced the slider with a new one. I've created a field for that in my redux config page. Now I can use this code:

```
<?php echo $redux_demo['mslider-id']; ?>
```

but I don't know how can I add this to my first code. I want to replace the id number "21", with this 2nd code.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php You're missing the basics of php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to get the value from option table like this

```
$metaid = get_option('mslider-id'); //get the value of mslider which saves from admin.

echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="'.$var.'"]');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried this:
`<?php 
$metaid = 'mslider-id';
echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="'.$metaid.'"]');
?>`

but not working, as it is missing the global $redux_demo. I'm not a pro in php & still learning. so don't know how to make it work.

Comment: You need to get the value of mslider-id and then use it with short code to call. I have updated my answer look into that

Comment: thanks for your help. yes I missed that part. now it is working fine.